# Cluster analysis for unsupervised problems - validation which don't depend on the proximity measure

Tags: validation, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Are there any internal validity indices/methods to evaluate the quality of my algorithm, which don't mostly depend on the proximity measure (e.g., distance matrix)?
All the conventional measures (such as: silhouette, Dunn index, N-cut, DB index, etc.) depends on how well you defined a proximity over the data and on the final partition, rather the data itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "depending on the data itself", data is an abstract term which can describe set of elephants or rings isomorphisms. In order to define **any** index you need to use one of two things:

- In supervised scenario (when you **know** some class of objects, not neceserly use it for trianing, but you have to **know** them) you can use these labels to calculate impurity, or any other classification derived score
- in unsupervised scenario you **have to use some similarity measure**, which can be very arbitrary, it might be an inverse of some metric, but it might be completely abstract measure derived from asking some people "are these element similar?", it might consists elements that are not comparable ("nans" in the matrix), it might be not symmetric, but **some similarity measure is crucial**, there is no "magical", "deep" meaning "in the data". You may extract similarity measure from some different models (like generative models, autoencoders etc.) but it is still the same conceptually, simply instead of giving the rules by hand, you give an algorithm by hand which extracts the rules.

To sum up. **You cannot evaluate a clustering as such**, you can only **evaluate how well it works for a particular task**, and this task can be:

- some bigger problem, where clustering is just one of the steps and you plug your clustering and observe change in the whole system's quality
- optimization of some class-based criterion (supervised)
- optimization of some similarity/distance based criterion (unsupervised)

There are no more options. Unsupervised learning is **not** a real, **well posed problem**, this is only **a tool** to simplify some real problems. As a result you won't ever be able to say "this clustering is good", you might only say that "this clustering is good in task A,B,C under assumption of pipelines X,Y,Z"